# Civicrm 5.57.0 Error on Contact Notes View

Tags: wordpress, contacts, error

Civicrm 5.57.0 on Wordpress 6.1.1
Within a single contact you can leave notes. since the last update, if you want to view the notes, this error appears in the log file and nothing come up. When I press edit, the content of the note comes up. This is now the workaround to view the notes, just to press edit.

```
Jan 13 08:14:53  [error]
$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
  "message" => "Expected to find one Note record, but there were multiple."
  "code" => null
  "exception" => CRM_Core_Exception {#8316
    -errorData: array:1 [
      "error_code" => 0
    ]
    #cause: null
    -_trace: null
    #message: "Expected to find one Note record, but there were multiple."
    #code: 0
    #file: "/var/www/civicrm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Array.php"
    #line: 1232
    trace: {
      /var/www/civicrm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Array.php:1232 {
        › else {
        ›   throw new \CRM_Core_Exception("Expected to find one {$recordTypeLabel}, but there were multiple.");
        › }
      }
      /var/www/civicrm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/Result.php:90 { …}
      /var/www/civicrm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/View/Note.php:37 { …}
      /var/www/civicrm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/View/Note.php:187 { …}
      /var/www/civicrm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:319 { …}
      /var/www/civicrm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69 { …}
      /var/www/civicrm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …}
      /var/www/civicrm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1199 { …}
      /var/www/civicrm/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:308 { …}
      /var/www/civicrm/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:332 { …}
      /var/www/civicrm/wp-includes/plugin.php:517 { …}
      /var/www/civicrm/wp-admin/admin.php:259 { …}
    }
  }
]


Jan 13 08:14:53  [debug] $backTrace = #0 /var/www/civicrm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(441): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /var/www/civicrm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(39): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CRM_Core_Exception))
#2 /var/www/civicrm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1199): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#3 /var/www/civicrm/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#4 /var/www/civicrm/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#5 /var/www/civicrm/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#6 /var/www/civicrm/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#7 {main}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this on https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org ? I tried but it seems to work ok.  Probably worth upgrading to 5.57.1 anyway as it has a few fixes.

Comment: No sorry, I can´t reproduce this on wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org. But this is on version 5.59.alpha. Next I will update to 5.57.2 and hope this bug is gone! I will report!

Comment: So, I updated to Version 5.57.3, same error and it´s not possible to view the notes...

Comment: I have the same issue. I have verified that only one tuple exists in the database for the user viewed.

Comment: Did anyone solve this issue? I still have it on a CiviCRM 5.58.1.

Comment: Yes, it still exists! I am on CiviCRm  5.58.1 and the same Error!
The Workaround is don't view the message, just press edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I found a fix:**

I found out that this error is related to CiviMobileAPI. If this extension is deactivated everything works again. I found this error message regarding this:

[php:warn] [pid 235173] [client] PHP Warning:  foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in /var/www/civicrm/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/com.agiliway.civimobileapi/CRM/CiviMobileAPI/ApiWrapper/Note.php on line 35, referer: https://domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontact%2Fview&reset=1&cid=3&selectedChild=note

Edit the file:

civicrm/ext/com.agiliway.civimobileapi/CRM/CiviMobileAPI/ApiWrapper/Note.php

https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civimobileapi/-/merge_requests/72/diffs